# Getting a "The page isn't redirecting properly" when logging into Tumblr

Tags: tumblr, login, firefox

Up until now (even earlier today) logging into Tumblr has worked perfectly. But I just tried to log in, and Firefox gave me this error:

> The page isn't redirecting properly
>
> Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.

I've tried it with Google Chrome, and I get the same error. It only happens when I log into Tumblr, not when I'm logged out. Apparently, [other users are getting this error too](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20111219200744AAKCbGr).

How can I fix this? Clearing cookies doesn't seem to help.